Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at publicRoutes.js:8:14)
I am trying to create separete route folder  the render it from Apps.. Everything  ok  but in console it show  me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at publicRoutes.js:8:14) this error.I used Vite for create react app
import { lazy } from "react";

const Login = lazy(() => import("../../views/auth/Login"));
const Register = lazy(() => import("../../views/auth/Register"));
const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    element: <Register />,
  },
];
export default publicRoutes;```

it's a js file.. 


It should show me the content of the element when i visit those path. but it show me unexpected token '<'

